What font should I use if some kanji are not displaying properly?
For example, if I open the Wiktionary page for 達, I can view it and several other kanji without issue, but there are others that do not display. The following screenshot will show what I mean.


In the composition section, it shows the first component properly, but the other component looks like a blank space. However, I can still click on it and open the page for it.
In the Descendants section, it shows a number of the kanji properly, but it displays the others as five thick horizontal bars.

When I click on the second component, I get a page like the following.


There are blank spaces where the kanji should be.
The character displays itself as a question mark in a square on the page tab.

Oh, and if I copy and paste the character in an Excel spreadsheet, it displays as a question mark in a square.
For the record, I have the "MS Gothic" and "MS Mincho" fonts, but it seems that they are not sufficient for displaying some kanji.
What fonts do you recommend for displaying such kanji in Wiktionary, Excel, and so on?

Inspect the font using your browser.  My browser says it's SimSun ExtB.
